# How to open general options view from alert of swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, settings, uialertview, openurl

I'm using this code to try open general settings iOS from my app, but this opens the settings Application view, not the general.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "IMPORTANT",
    message: "Camera access required for QR Scanning",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert
)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Allow", style: .cancel, handler: { (alert) -> Void in
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:] )
}))
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is possible open general view using a correct code to avoid rejection from Apple like using "App-Prefs:root=General"?

Comment: AFAIK you can't (or shouldn't as the URL (you would need to use) is consider a "private api" and will have your App rejected if you try and submit it to the App Store)

Answer (score 0):

Navigation user to your application settings is the right approach recommended by Human Interface Guidelines:

> **Provide shortcuts to Settings when appropriate.** If your app includes text that directs users to Settings, such as “Go to Settings > MyApp > Privacy > Location Services,” provide a button that opens that location automatically. For developer guidance, see openSettingsURLString in UIApplication.
>   https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/settings/

User can manipulate with all settings related to your application including allowing and disabling access to camera (what you need).